# Strange/Unpredictable Transparent Background Bug In Winforms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been experiencing a very strange bug with a Winforms application, where showing a hidden form may result in that form's buttons & backgrounds coming up transparent.  Buttons can be subsequently revealed by moving the mouse over them, as if the form hadn't been properly invalidated/drawn.  For instance, a form that looks like this:
[image: Correct appearance]

May come up like this:[image: Actual appearance]

Moving the mouse around causes the buttons to draw: [image: More buttons visible]

Here's a short video to show exactly how it behaves: http://screencast.com/t/XmFSPfLw.  Explicitly calling Invalidate() or Refresh() in the Show event doesn't fix it.

What's strange is that this issue appears only on SOME computers, and I haven't been able to discern anything that those computers have in common.

- I've seen it happen in different versions of Windows 7 (Embedded, x64, and x86) - but not all instances of any of those.
- All systems are running the same version of .NET, and all have been fully updated.
- On systems where it happens, it only happens when showing a form that'd been previously shown & hidden; it occurs when re-showing it (i.e. never the very first time the form is created & shown).
- On systems where it happens, it doesn't happen for all forms, and isn't even consistent with the forms for which it happens (example of several subsequent hides/shows, sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't: http://screencast.com/t/liQ53p8Sce).
- On systems where it happens, it only happens if the application is scaled to the full resolution of the screen.  I use Control.Scale() to scale each form up to a user-specified resolution; if that's the same as the screen resolution, the bug may happen on some systems; if it's scaled up to anything less, I've never seen it happen (example: here's the same video as the first one above; with the form scaled to less than the full screen resolution, it doesn't happen: http://screencast.com/t/k87zJDeSYPGL).

I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out what's different about the systems that exhibit the issue, and why it's happening in the first place.  I literally had to have a client ship me a laptop that shows the issue, as I couldn't reproduce it on any systems I have here.  I'm really at a loss as to the cause...

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Never figured out the cause. However, I was able to prevent it from happening by calling this.Owner.Refresh() *after* this.Owner.Show().